# PCB Black Spot: Leakage?

Tags: hardware, restoration, repair

[Photo album, sorry for the hassle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQD4r.jpg)

Quick question: Ceramic disk capacitor has leaked? Or a dodgy soldering technique?
This is a quite old calculator, it's an arbitrary model nowhere to be found.
Any information as to what could've happened is appreciated.
Thanks beforehand!

**edit:**

Added more images of what looks like a burnt case and the bottom of the number input panel

Comment: I wonder if a previous capacitor in that spot exploded and caused the damage you see?

Comment: That is definitly more heat than leakage.

Comment: Looks to me like careless or dodgy soldering; the other pics show the components not flush to the board, which was unusual (except in hand-made 'kits').

Comment: @traal No idea... AFAIK it was factory made and never hand-fixed

Comment: @tofro Oh... I see... I guess heat dissipation due to bad voltage

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Welp. Then my grandfather either was a dodgy solderer (sorry for the butcher lol) or this was poorly factory-made

Comment: If you don't mind licensing the images under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) then I could edit them directly into the post for you.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like long-term heat damage from a hot running component, especially given how PCB and Case are equally damaged. Not unlikely the transistor which has drossy looking solder joints (look like heat above 180°C remelted them) and looks like it has SPLIT IN HALF from overheating.